# Encapsulate URL to fix 404 error on react js application page when we reload/refresh

Tags: wordpress, reactjs, routes, apache2

I have created a site using react js. It is working fine on my local system using `browserHistory` but not working on my production server. The first time it loads properly. When I refresh the page it gives me "page not found" error.

I have tried using `hashHistory`. It resolved my issue but I am looking for a better solution because I don't want complex URL `hashHistory` which includes # and a random key. (We want it to encapsulate to something like http://example.com/about and not like http://example.com/#/about?_k=9yfmfq )

My webpack.config.js code -

```
module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './src/index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel'
    }]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: './',
    port: 3000
  }
};
```

Looking for a solution in apache2. Sorry for asking a noob question.

Comment: So... it is a node.js app?

Comment: No.On the backend I have user WordPress. I have sent axios request from react js to WordPress

Comment: the code you provide is for dev server? Where is your production configuration? Are you using any server like apache or nginx?

Comment: You need post more information about your setup of Wordpress. Why do you use Wordpress? How do you use it? Your problem is messing up routing systems of your Wordpress and ReactJS application. You need to set up it correctly. But without any information about your solution stack it is very difficult for others to answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

The Problem is When you load for the first time one `yourdomain.com`, your server serve the index.html file as default. So, when you try `yourdomain.com/something`, your server try to find that file but as its not there, it will send 404. You have to configure your server to redirect all page request to `index.html` file.

Here is a simple `nginx` configuration for `single page application`-

```
location / {
    try_files $uri /index.html;
}
```

this will redirect all url to index.html which will load your javascript and then all the routes will handled by javascript.

Comment: Hi Thanks. Can you please let me know what set should I follow for apache2 server?

Comment: you should google it as `apache single page application`.

Comment: ok. I will search. If you already know the solution, please share.